# Generators of tensor Product of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $k$. Then their tensor product is a pair $(T,\phi)$ where $T$ is a vector space over $k$, and $\phi:V\times W\rightarrow T$ is a bilinear map satisfying:

Given any vector space $X$ and  bilinear map $f:V\times W\rightarrow X$, there is unique linear map $f^*:T\rightarrow X$ such that $f^*\circ \phi=f$.

If $\{v_i:i\in I\}$ and $\{w_j:j\in J\}$ are bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively, I want to show that $\{\phi(v_i,w_j): i\in I, j\in J\}$ is a basis of $T$.

I proved that this set spans $T$ using universal property.

But, I am facing problem in showing that this set is independent, *using universal property*. Can one give some hint to prove the independence?

(What is my problem: If $\sum_{i,j}a_{ij} \phi(v_i,w_j)=0$, where sum is finite, and all coefficients are non-zero, I want to get a contradiction. But, I am not able to pick up properly a vector space $X$ and bilinear map $f:V\times W\rightarrow X$, to apply universal property and arrive at contradiction. (There may be different way, but I tried this way to go with universal property and arrive at contradiction).

Comment: You can show (using the universal property) that the tensor product preserves direct sums in each variable. This reduces the question to the $1$-dimensional case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints towards one possible approach:

First show using the universal property that if $V$ and $W$ are one-dimensional with bases $v$ and $w$ respectively, then $V\otimes W$ is also one-dimensional with basis $v\otimes w$.

In the general case if $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ is a basis of $V$ and $(w_j)_{j\in J}$ is a basis of $W$, write the direct sums
$$V=\sum_i V_i\qquad\text{and}\qquad W=\sum_j V_j$$
where $V_i$ is the span of $v_i$ and $W_j$ is the span of $w_j$. Show using the universal property that we have the direct sum
$$V\otimes W=\sum_{i,j}V_i\otimes W_j$$

It follows from this that $(v_i\otimes w_j)_{i\in I,j\in J}$ is a basis of $V\otimes W$.

Admittedly each of these steps takes some thought and work.